# how to properly pass a query parameter representing a map?

Tags: java, spring-boot, scala

I have this API

````
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._


@GET
@Produces(Array(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
@Path("/somepath/{id}")
def query(
                 @PathParam("id") Id: Long,
                 @DefaultValue("25") @QueryParam("perPage") perPage: Int,
                 @DefaultValue("1") @QueryParam("page") page: Int,
                 @DefaultValue("label") @QueryParam("sort") sorts: java.util.List[String],
                 @QueryParam("filters") filters: String,
               ): String = {
  ....
val filter = parse(filters)
....
  }```

Why is it that when I try calling it like this
````

````
val filterMap = Map(
  "filters" -> Seq(
    Map(
      "field" -> "listType",
      "operator" -> "Equals",
      "values" -> Seq("filter")
    )
  )
)

val filtersInJson = write(filterMap)
val encodedFilters = URLEncoder.encode(filtersInJson, "UTF-8")

given.body(Map()).when
  .get(s"/somepath/{id}?page=1&perPage=25&sort=label&filters=$encodedFilters")
  .then()
  .statusCode(200)```
````

I get the following error and never enter the function
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid number of path parameters. Expected 1, was 0. Undefined path parameters are: "filters":[{"field":"listType","operator":"Equals","values":["filter"].

I thought maybe I was supposed to pass a json and tried that but it doesn't work. Also, when I call the function from json with the exact same arguments as what encodedFilters is set to, it works. Even if I call it with %7B%7D it works in postman but not from the code

Comment: The code you're showing us for the test doesn't use the same path as what is defined above. Is that a typo? When do you get the error you're showing? From the test or from the response of the endpoint?

Comment: That being said, I wouldn't send raw JSON in a query parameter. Use multiple query params, or encode the JSON as base64 for instance, or use the body if makes sense for your use case.

Comment: Yes that was a typo. The problem is when I send the encoded request, I can't decode it using parse(json), so I think I am missing something because I can send an encoded message through postman. So I think there's some conversion into json along the way by spring boot? Not, sure, any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: You didn't show us what the `parse` method do. What's the value of `filters` received? Did you try to debug?

Comment: My guess is that you want to be sending the inner map of `filterMap`.

Comment: I edited it to show it. And what do you mean sending the map of filterMap? I send in the encoded map, it works if I send it in through postman but not with this UT

Comment: Debug the encoded string you're sending vs. the one you expect to parse. I believe you're adding an extra `filters` wrapping level in your encoding that you don't expect when parsing. Of you have a postman request that works, compare the postman request vs. The one you're actually sending.